# what is the difference between binary, sparse and categorical in class_mode

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

> below the code for understanding,

```
#Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1.0 / 255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1.0 / 255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/training_set',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary'
)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/test_set',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary'
)
```

> When I used  **sparse** / **categorical**. It show the same output,

**Below the output,**

```
Found 214 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 20 images belonging to 5 classes.
```

**Note:** This code is for training datasets but unfortunately it doesn't train

**So need help**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are related to [loss function](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/).

The `'binary'` class mode gives you a number of each class. For example if your dataset has 3 class A, B, C the target data will be 0 for class A, 1 for B and 2 for C.

The `categorical` gives you [one hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot), `(1, 0, 0)` for A, `(0, 1, 0)` for B and `(0, 0, 1)` for C.

You can look for different with this.

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/test_set',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary'
)
x, y = test_set[0]
print(y.shape)  # (32,)
print(y)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/test_set',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)
x, y = test_set[0]
print(y.shape)  # (32, n) where n is equal to how many folder you have in 'dataset/test_set'
print(y)
```

The `sparse` is not used in `flow_from_directory` and usually used when an image can be more than one class. For example if an image can be A and C the target will be `(1, 0, 1)`.

The reason for `binary` actually called this way because at the earlier versions it only gives you 1 and 0.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator
One of "categorical", "binary", "sparse", "input", or None. Default: "categorical". Determines the type of label arrays that are returned:

```
"categorical" will be 2D one-hot encoded labels,
"binary" will be 1D binary labels,
"sparse" will be 1D integer labels,
"input" will be images identical to input images (mainly used to work with autoencoders).
If None, no labels are returned (the generator will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use with model.predict()). Please note that in case of class_mode None, the data still needs to reside in a subdirectory of directory for it to work correctly.
```